# why there is nothing appears on chrome after coding with html?

Tags: html, css

I started learning HTML and CSS, I write an HTML code but the expected result is not appearing on chrome or internet explorer, I made sure that the code syntax is correct and the file saved with its name .html, everything appears normal and good with the code but why there is nothing appearing on chrome??
thank you.
This is a simple code that I'm trying to see on chrome.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- HTML Project-->
<head>
   <meta keywords="htmls, teach, learn" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <title> HTML WEBSITE </title>
</head>

<body> 
    <div style="color : blue;">
         THIS IS MY NEW WEBSITE
     </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide your actual code as well a sample of what is appearing and a description of what's wrong with it. We can't help you as is.

Comment: We couldn't possibly begin to answer your question without a [mcve] in the question. Please update it with one.

Comment: yes, sure I added a sample code.

Comment: please share style.css code, it works fine without it, there might be some issue in your styles.css

Comment: @FahadMahmood, that shouldn't matter unless there is something going on with the `body`. Inline style takes the highest precedence.

Comment: definitely, but the inline style just changes the color to blue, there might be another style that is hiding the div.